# Docker Entrypoint not running as root on jupyterhub

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, jupyter, jupyterhub

We are trying to run a docker entrypoint as root in a docker image used by our jupyterhub for the single user servers. We need root to add a host to access an internal git registry from within a single user jupyter notebook server on a jupyterhub running on K8S by it's domain.

We already tried adding the domain to the `/etc/hosts` file in the docker image which is loaded for the single user servers by our jupyterhub in a docker-entrypoint script (code can be seen at the bottom).

However we get a permission denied when trying to add the host.
The printouts also show why:

Locally, the first whoami shows `root` , as we expected.
On the jupyter notebook started in a pod by our jupyterhub (running on K8s) however, the first printout already shows `jovyan`.

The same effect can be seen when directly printing out whoami in the entrypoint in the Dockerfile like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "echo $(whoami)"]
```

Meaning that it is the whole entrypoint, that does not get executed as root but the user is somehow switched beforehand.

Can we prevent this behaviour or is there a good workaround?

Any help appreciated, thank you in advance!
PS:
Additionally, when we try to run `exec su - "jovyan"` in the entrypoint-script on the jupyterhub, we are getting the error, that the su command has to be run from a terminal. Locally it works without problems.

---

Code of docker-entrypoint script (just for reference):

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:1145fb1198b2
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

USER root

...

COPY aai-entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/aai-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/aai-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/src/app/my-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ""
```

We added the empty CMD to overwrite the CMD of the jupyter base-notebook

**my-entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(whoami)
echo "xx.xxx.xxx   our.domain.com" >> /etc/hosts
echo "test"
exec su - "jovyan"
echo $(whoami)

# to not overwrite the entrypoint of the jupyter/base-notebook
# see https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/base-notebook/Dockerfile
exec tini -g -- "start-notebook.sh"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaner Solution:

Thanks to a gitHub user who provided me with a cleaner solution:
You can use kube-dns to add the hosts to the known hosts of Kubernetes, making them available for the deployments on there.

Link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#kube-dns

Alternative:

As we planned on granting the users sudo access no matter what (no big risk as containers are only there temporarily), the GRANT_SUDO configuration already resolves that problem. If granting sudo, the entrypoint will also be run as root. Changing to jovyan in the script might still be a good idea.

You can set the GRANT_SUDO setting for jupyterhub by:

- adding it as an [environment variable the jupyterhub_config.py](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/spawner.html?highlight=c.spawner%20environment)
- in the [config.yaml used by your helm chart](https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/issues/562)

If you don't want to grant the user sudo access, this still could be a working solution for you, as you might remove the sudo rights for jovyan in the script again. I have not tried that out though, as it is not wanted in our scenario.

Hope this helps someone.